# DEBUG (7): Security problem: block_name has not been whitelisted. (Magento system.log)

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, debugging, system.log, whitelist

In the `system.log` file of my Magento install I have the following error message

> DEBUG (7): Security problem: `block_name` has not been whitelisted.

where `block_name` is the name of a block used in my store.

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This message means that one of the blocks that is used in your Magento store is not on the whitelist.

With [Security Patch SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) and [Magento CE 1.9.2.2](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.2.html) a new whitelist for blocks was introduced. Magento now includes a white list of allowed blocks or directives. If a module or extension uses variables like `{{config path=”web/unsecure/base_url”}}` and `{{block type=rss/order_new}}` in CMS pages or emails, and the directives are not on this list, you will need to add them with your database. If a block is not on the whitelist it will not be rendered.

**Error**

As of [Security Patch SUPEE-7405](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405) and [Magento CE 1.9.2.3](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.3.html) there is a new core feature which will easily identify blocks that are missing from the whitelist for you. The `blockDirective($construction)` function in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
```

was updated and now looks like this:

```
/**
 * Retrieve Block html directive
 *
 * @param array $construction
 * @return string
 */
public function blockDirective($construction)
{
    $skipParams = array('type', 'id', 'output');
    $blockParameters = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    $block = null;

    if (isset($blockParameters['type'])) {
        if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
            $type = $blockParameters['type'];
            $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
        } else {
            Mage::log('Security problem: ' . $blockParameters['type'] . ' has not been whitelisted.');
        }
    } elseif (isset($blockParameters['id'])) {
        $block = $layout->createBlock('cms/block');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setBlockId($blockParameters['id']);
        }
    }

    if ($block) {
        $block->setBlockParams($blockParameters);
        foreach ($blockParameters as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($k, $skipParams)) {
                continue;
            }
            $block->setDataUsingMethod($k, $v);
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }

    if (isset($blockParameters['output'])) {
        $method = $blockParameters['output'];
    }
    if (!isset($method) || !is_string($method) || !method_exists($block, $method)) {
        $method = 'toHtml';
    }
    return $block->$method();
}
```

> **Notice the new**
>
> `Mage::log('Security problem: ' . $blockParameters['type'] . ' has not
>   been whitelisted.');`

If a block is missing from the whitelist then the system will detect it and print an error including the missing blocks name in the `system.log` file located in

```
[your magento install dir]/var/log/
```

Of course you must have logging enabled to get this message. This is the error you will see

> DEBUG (7): Security problem: `block_name` has not been whitelisted.

**How to fix**

To fix this you will have to manually add the missing blocks name to the whitelist. *Only add blocks that you trust. If you don't know where the block is coming from then find this out first.* Once you are sure that you want to add the missing block, then in your Magento Admin Panel go to

```
System > Permissions > Blocks
```

and click on the `Add New Block` button. From here you can add the missing block to the whitelist. Just enter the `block_name` that showed up in your error message in the `Block Name *` field, set `Is Allowed` to "Yes" and hit the `Save Block` button.

Don't forget to flush cache. Your missing block is now allowed and the error should be gone.